# magento 1.9.2.4 blank page when send mail

Tags: magento-1.9, send-mail

I am working on website Magento 1.9.2.4 and having weird issue, 
Wherever mail function is called in whole website, it shows blank page only.
Events can be customer registration, place order button or even forget password event.

Comment: What is the error, Can you show your exception.log, error.log data?

Comment: please enable Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); and check what is the error

Comment: i also enable Mage::setIsDevloperMode(true); but nothing will print in screen

Comment: nothing will print in exception.log

Comment: Is there mail server installed on your server like smtp or anything like that. Without mail-server you will not be able to send mails from your server.

Comment: Also if you post some error.log and exception.log then it will be easier for debugging.

Comment: in console it shows 500 internal server error. nothing will print in error log